# Is it possible to expire data of specific key from gemfire region like redis

Tags: spring-boot, redis, gemfire, spring-data-gemfire, geode

Hi I am new to gemfire and i want to exprire data from gemfire region for specific key after idle time which I set.

i did  this using redis by below code.

```
jedis.set(key, value);
config.setMaxIdle(50);
jedis.expire(key, config.getMaxIdle());
```

but how to do it in gemfire.

Any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete data for specific region then try following code :

```
Region<String, String> region = cache .<String, String> createClientRegionFactory( ClientRegionShortcut.CACHING_PROXY) .setEntryTimeToLive(new ExpirationAttributes(50)) .create(PropertiesCache.getInstance().getProperty("region"));
```

It's works in my situation.

Answer (score 2):

You can control the expiration of individual keys if you configure the region to use a custom expiration. You provide an implementation of the CustomExpiry interface that can look at each entry and decide when it should expire. For example:

```
RegionFactory regionFactory = ...
regionFactory.setCustomEntryIdleTimeout(new CustomExpiry() {
    public ExpirationAttributes getExpiry(Entry entry) {
      if(entry.getKey().equals("XXX")) {
        return new ExpirationAttributes(50, ExpirationAction.INVALIDATE); 
      }
    }
});
```